# Internet explorer hangs while loading a website

Tags: html, internet-explorer

When loading a website (*censored*), it hangs for a couple of seconds before loading the page (up to a minute on older ones of internet explorer)
In other browsers it works fine.

It's a basic wordpress website with a couple of javascript and stylesheets, nothing to fancy. Firebug doesn't show anything weird in the NET-panel, all files exist.

Also with some other sites using the same plugin (for the properties), the same problem exists. So it should be plugin related, but I can't find why.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I loaded up IE9 and it loads quick.  However, if you turn on IE9 dev tools, go to network, switch to IE8 standards mode and start capturing, you will see a lot of 404s on images that do not occur when using IE9 standards.  This may be the issue.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, never came to mind to look in the IE dev tools. The 404 images were the problem. You can post it as the answer :-)
Underlaying cause was that the images are not relative to the css, but to the document root (in the filter css-property that is)

Comment: If that solved the problem, @Matt that would be fine as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I loaded up IE9 and it loads quick. However, if you turn on IE9 dev tools, go to network, switch to IE8 standards mode and start capturing, you will see a lot of 404s on images that do not occur when using IE9 standards. This may be the issue. Good luck. – Matt Feb 23 at 16:55

Just to get the question answered, thanks @Matt